# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The TEMPLATE_DIRS setting must be a tuple. Please fix your settings

Tags: django

Hey I'm trying to learn how to use django, I have very basic knowledge and I'm pretty confused with whats happening right now.. So I'm trying to follow some online video tutorial and I'm a bit stuck, so I was wondering if someone could help.. I'm on a mac and I'm in terminal and it's telling me 
'django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The TEMPLATE_DIRS setting must be a tuple. Please fix your settings.' And on top of that theres heaps more lines and things that I don't understand! Anyway, I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me with what to do, I really have no clue.. Furthermore the annoying thing with the online videos is, normally I email the presenter with my problems and he gets back to me a few days later, so do you know any other good resources other than here, that have a strong django community where I can also ask questions and learn django.. THANKS

Answer (score 15):

Seems like you forgot to add the comma in the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting.  You have something like this:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
)
```

But it should be:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

Note the comma after the `os.path.join()` call.